# PHP function not giving back the variable

Tags: php, function

Sorry i am a beginner and i got stuck in this :(
Why is this php function not working? My $code variable is empty. If i put the IF to my main.php the code is working perfect.

**My functions.php:**

```
function location_zone($location) {
    if ($location=='TEXT1' ) {
        $code='10101';
    }
    if ($location=='TEXT2' ) {
        $code='10201';
    }
    if ($location=='TEXT3' ) {
        $code='10301';
    }
}
```

**My main.php:**

```
    require 'functions.php';
    $location=$_POST['location'];
    $code = location_zone($location);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Add this to the end of the function: `return $code;`

Comment: I am closing question as non-reproducable or caused by a TYPO as return statement is missing in function: `return $code;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value at the end of the function like this

```
function location_zone($location) {
    if ($location=='TEXT1' ) {
        $code='10101';
    }
    if ($location=='TEXT2' ) {
        $code='10201';
    }
    if ($location=='TEXT3' ) {
        $code='10301';
    }
    return $code;
}
```

Comment: Oh... I did it but still nothing in $code variable.... I'm using xampp

Comment: this is because your function have not any default case. like if there is no if condition   works then what ?

Comment: Declare `$code` outside if statements, and use `if`, `else if` and `else` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
function location_zone($location) {
    print_r($location);
    if ($location=='TEXT1') {
        $code='10101';
    }
    if ($location=='TEXT2') {
        $code='10201';
    }
    if ($location=='TEXT3') {
        $code='10301';
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($code);
    echo "</pre>;
    exit();
}
```

What does it output to the screen when you try this?

Comment: Thanks for your help... i changed the if to elseif and now it is working ;)